# Converting sugars with yeast

Tags: bread, sugar, yeast

What percentage of sugar gets converted into CO2 with yeast fermentation in any baked item?

Comment: More detail needed: recipe?  Rising time?  Quantity and type of yeast (fresh, dry, or sourdough)?  

Also, the sugar doesn't get "converted into C02".  It's gets converted into a variety of things, mostly alcohol, and CO2 is a minority byproduct.

Comment: As above, it is impossible to answer this exactly. Temperature has a very large impact on this too. Even in winemaking where all the available sugars are fermented there are both aerobic growth phases where more CO2 and less alcohol is made and the anaerobic phase (fermentation itself) where alcohol is the intended byproduct.